# AngujarJS Form dependency using ngOptions and prepopulate selected field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

I have a form with the return JSON object which contains a set of countries with their state/province and their cities.  I am setting up the form using AngularJS 1.6.x and required to have multiple selected fields depending on its parent value.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('AddressApp', []);

  app.controller('AddressController', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{
      "name": "US",
      "label": "United States",
      "state_province": [{
          "name": "WA",
          "label": "Washington",
          "city": [{
              "name": "Seattle"
            },
            {
              "name": "Tocoma"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "OR",
          "label": "Oregon",
          "city": [{
            "name": "Portland"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "name": "CA",
      "label": "Canada",
      "state_province": [{
          "name": "BC",
          "label": "British Columbia",
          "city": [{
              "name": "Vancouver"
            },
            {
              "name": "Victoria"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "AB",
          "label": "Alberta",
          "city": [{
              "name": "Calgary"
            },
            {
              "name": "Edmonton"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }];

    // Code to preselect fields
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.user.country = "US";
    $scope.user.stateProvince = "WA";
    $scope.user.city = "Seattle";

    if ($scope.user.country !== undefined && $scope.user.country != "") {
      for (var countryIndex = 0; countryIndex < $scope.countries.length; countryIndex++) {
        var country = $scope.countries[countryIndex];
        if (country.name == $scope.user.country) {
          $scope.selectedCountry = country;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if ($scope.user.stateProvince != undefined && $scope.user.stateProvince != "" && $scope.selectedCountry != null) {
      for (var stateIndex = 0; stateIndex < $scope.selectedCountry.state_province.length; stateIndex++) {
        var state = $scope.selectedCountry.state_province[stateIndex];
        if (state.name == $scope.user.stateProvince) {
          $scope.selectedStateProvince = state;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if ($scope.user.city != undefined && $scope.user.city != "" && $scope.selectedStateProvince != null) {
      for (var cityIndex = 0; cityIndex < $scope.selectedStateProvince.city.length; cityIndex++) {
        var city = $scope.selectedStateProvince.city[cityIndex];
        if (city.name == $scope.user.city) {
          $scope.selectedCity = city;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    input.ng-invalid,
    select.ng-invalid {
      border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="AddressApp" ng-controller="AddressController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <h1>Location</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.label for country in countries"></select>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.country" value="{{user.country=selectedCountry.name}}" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">State/Province:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="selectedStateProvince" ng-options="state.label for state in selectedCountry.state_province" ng-disabled="selectedCountry===undefined"></select>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.stateProvince" value="{{user.stateProvince=selectedStateProvince.name}}" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city.name for city in selectedStateProvince.city" ng-disabled="selectedStateProvince===undefined"></select>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.city" value="{{user.city=selectedCity.name}}" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" ng-disabled="form.invalid" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">{{$valid}}</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need the limit the user's viewable option so the user can first choose a country, then state/province, then city. Once another country is chosen then the state/province will update accordingly.   I am able to show the form by using the AngularJS 1.6.x with the ng-Options attribute.  However, if the user has already populated data before the page is loaded, I want to return to the form with some object preselected. For now, I can only use the a for loop to search for the same value within the countries object and return the selected object back to those selected ng-model. For example, if the user has already entered field "user.country" below, I will have to write a for loop in order to return the correct object so the subsequence select fields will work.

Is there a way I can simplify this so I can get both objects and their name below without passing through the entry object to pre-populate the form selection form and still have the object work in this form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out that I have to change the data structure to use key value pair for easier setup.

Solution as follow:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('AddressApp', []);

  app.controller('AddressController', function($scope) {


    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.country = "CA";
    $scope.user.state = "BC";

    $scope.countries = {
      US: {
        "label": "United States",
        "state_province": {
          "WA": {
            "label": "Washington",
            "city": {
              "Seattle": {},
              "Tocoma": {}
            }
          },
          "OR": {
            "label": "Oregon",
            "city": {
              "Portland": {}
            }
          }
        },
      },
      CA: {
        "label": "Canada",
        "state_province": {
          "BC": {
            "label": "British Columbia",
            "city": {
              "Vancouver": {},
              "Victoria": {}
            }
          },
          "AB": {
            "label": "Alberta",
            "city": {
              "Calgary": {},
              "Edmonton": {}
            }
          }
        },
      }
    };
  });

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    input.ng-invalid,
    select.ng-invalid {
      border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="AddressApp" ng-controller="AddressController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <h1>Location</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="user.country" ng-options="key as value.label for (key, value) in countries"></select>
            <br/> user.country: {{user.country}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">State/Province:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="user.state" ng-options="key as value.label for (key, value) in countries[user.country].state_province" ng-disabled="user.country===undefined"></select>
            <br/> user.state: {{user.state}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="user.city" ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in countries[user.country].state_province[user.state].city" ng-disabled="user.state===undefined"></select>
            <br/> user.state: {{user.city}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This way, I have have the ng-models set and have the dependencies of the form populated correctly.